# How to style only elements of a type that have not text nodes as siblings?

Tags: javascript, nodes

I have this markup:

```
<div class="wysiwyg">
  <em>It has to be red because is the only em element</em>
</div>


<div class="wysiwyg">
  Some text
  <em>Not to be red because has previous (and following) text node</em>
  Some text
</div>


<div class="wysiwyg">
  <em>It has to be red because its' a em in a div that has only ems and no text node / </em>
  <em>It has to be red because its' a em in a div that has only ems and no text node</em>
```

I would like to apply a `element.style.color = "red";` only to the `<ems>` element that are the only `<em>`s children of its parent or that have other `<em>`s as sibling but not text node as sibling.

Also, I would like to know how to style text nodes only with some like `node.style.color = blue;` (I know that `.style` method apply only to elements...).

Thanks!

Comment: What if an `<em>` has another element, such as a `<span>` as a sibling? Or multiple `<em>`, and other elements, as siblings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you'd like a native JavaScript solution, and you can target at least EcmaScript 5, here is a solution https://jsfiddle.net/pjhuptt3/.

I'm using `childNodes` to get all the child nodes including text nodes too. Also, I'm checking the `nodeType` to be equal to `3` (text nodes), and I have to check if the text node is not a white-space.

Please note that the code is only for example purposes and for demonstrating the tools you have. Not tested or optimized in any manner.

```
function hasTextNodes(node) {
  if (!node || !node.childNodes.length) return false;

  for (var i=0;i<node.childNodes.length;++i) {
    var child = node.childNodes[i];
    // check if the node is text node and check if it's not a white space
    if (child.nodeType == 3 && child.textContent && child.textContent.trim().length)
      return true;
  }
  return false;    
}

document.querySelectorAll(".wysiwyg").forEach(function(node) { 
  if (!hasTextNodes(node))
    node.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; 
});
```

If you'd like to style the `em` elements, you can do something like this.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".wysiwyg").forEach(function(node) { 
  if (!hasTextNodes(node)) {
    // query the em direct children
    node.querySelectorAll("> em").forEach(function(em) {
      em.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; 
    });
  }
});
```

Just for the sake of completeness, I should tell you that unless you need this exact scenario (for example it's some educational exercise), there are several better ways to achieve this same thing.

- First of all, anytime you find yourself giving some "meaning" to a text node, you shouldn't make it a text node anymore. You should wrap them to a `span` and add a specific class if you need to distinguish them in the future. So that way it's easier to deal with them, you can select them, style them, etc.
- Secondly, with a framework like `jQuery`, these kind of tasks are significantly easier to solve, and `jQuery` doesn't add so much overhead itself, especially if you reference it using a CDN.

Comment: Given that the code is pretty much the answer would you please include that code in your answer? By all means link to a JS Fiddle demo as well, but the answer should be self contained and understandable without having to look to an external site.

Comment: Great answer, @Zoltán ! And what about the "some text" text node? In Javascript can you select and style directly the text nodes or only html element? And is it your answer valid only for `em`s or for whatever element different from a text node? I would like highlight only the `em`s, not a `<span>` if is present...   Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to style a text node with javascript, nor with css of course. The answer doesn't depend on the exact elements, so it should work whatever elements you have. If you want to highlight the `em`s only, you have to slightly modify the  code, I'll add a little code for that case.

Comment: Please, @ZoltánTamási, only a last thing: edit `node.querySelectorAll("> em").forEach(function(em) {` to the correct `node.querySelectorAll("> em").forEach(function(em) {`. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please point out where the mistake is? I've read your comment 10 times, but I see the two code identical.